# ODI 12c Installation and RCU Creation

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

Greetings.

I have a question regarding ODI 12c Installation and RCU creation. I want to install ODI 12c in my system. So I tried to download ODI 12c from Oracle Cloud. As per my previous experience, I should download ODI Installable (2 Disks) along with RCU component, that I downloaded for ODI 11g. But in case of 12c, I am not able to find any RCU executable. Instead of it I am able to find a component 'Oracle Fusion Middleware Infrastructure'. Could anyone please guide whether this component is responsible for Repository Creation (Master and Child). If not, then please suggest how to create Repositories for ODI 12c. It is a bit confusing this time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, from ODI 11.1.1.9 on wards we do not have any separate RCU but once you install ODI automatically we will get a RCU.bat file which can be executed to create repository.

Answer (score 0):

after install ODI , you can find repository creation utility at [ODI_HOME]\oracle_common\bin. Execute rcu.bat and then create repositories for ODI 12C.

Regards